# SqlLite Select where date and order by time

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this problem, I am trying to select by date and i also need to order by time in descending order. I am not sure if I am doing this right, because the application crashes after adding the code below. Please tell me if this query is correct?

```
public Cursor getAllDataDelete(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor
    cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {ID, TITLE,
            DESCRIPTION, DATE, TIME}, null, null, null, null, TIME + " ASC");

    return cursor;
```

Comment: `Cursor cursor;` typo and post the logcat details always

Comment: i don't have anything relevant displaying in the logcat, no errors, the app just closes

Comment: If the application closes logcat should show something. Make sure you're watching your application by selecting "Show only selected application" in your android monitor.

Comment: Do you have any `try`/`catch` in your code? If yes, why?

Comment: rebuild your app